# Parsing json data with recurring keys

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json object something like below which is having recurring keys , I just wanted to iterate throught,
but Object.keys has skipped to the last in events array, since the name is repeated, I could not change the response, needed to iterate
though it and get the values of id and value , and make id as a key and cvalue as value

```
var jsonObj = {
    "output": {
        "events": [
            {
                "name": "sys",
                "eventout": [
                    {
                        "name": "sys events",
                        "subenvent": [
                            {
                                "id": "test1_sys",
                                "cvalue": "something"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "test2_sys",
                                "cvalue": "something_else"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "name": "log",
                "eventout": [
                    {
                        "name": "Log events",
                        "eventout": [
                            {
                                "id": "test1_log",
                                "cvalue": "something_log"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "test2_log",
                                "cvalue": "something_else_log"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

wanted output like

```
{
  "test1_sys" : "something",
  "test2_sys" : "something_else",
  "test1_log" : "something_log",
  "test2_log" : "something_else_log"
}
```

I tried something but it is not working ,

```
      for (const key1 in data) {
            console.log("debug: ", data[key1]);
            Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
                console.table('Key : ' + key + ', Value : ' + data[key])
            });
            for (const key2 in data[key1]) {
              console.log("Debug2: ", data[key1][key2]);
              const test = data[key1][key2];
              Object.keys(test).forEach(function(key) {
                 console.table('Key : ' + key + ', Value : ' + test[key])
              });
            }
        }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That just isn't valid JSON, unless you pass it in as a string and write your own parser, you won't be able to do what you want to.

Comment: The data structure is bad, JSON cannot have repeated keys, should be events = [ { name, eventout }, {name, eventout}, ... ] instead

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/clarinet